# On load estimation of memory consumption of program, is it possible?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management

In the book "Fundamentos de sistemas operativos" (Gunnar Wolf, Esteban Ruiz, Federico Bergero, Erwin Meza p.254) it says:

> Al cargar un programa el sistema operativo calcula cuánta memoria va a
> requerir a lo largo de su vida prevista. Esto incluye el espacio
> requerido para la asignación dinámica de memoria con la familia de
> funciones malloc y free.

It translates to:

> When loading a program, the OS calculates how much memory it will
> consume along its expected life. This includes the space required for
> dynamic memory allocation with the `malloc` and `free` function family.

Is this even possible? Can the OS calculate a sensible bound on memory usage? If so does Linux do that on program load?

I cannot find any other reference that explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is incorrect.  With most OS's we use today, the OS does not try to calculate in advance how much memory the process will use.  Indeed, when we use dynamic memory allocation (such as malloc) it is typically impossible to predict how much memory the process might use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the operating system could do at best: It could examine your computer, and find out what is the maximum amount of memory that can be successfully allocated. For example, if you have so much RAM, so much space for swap space on your hard drive etc. the OS could figure out something like "if you try to allocate more than 197GB in total, some allocations will fail".

It *may* be possible for a C or C++ program to figure out how much memory will be needed so the program can proceed to the beginning of the main() function.

Comment: "It may be possible ... to figure out": practical cases are so rare that AFAIK compilers don't even try.

Comment: I think it's not that it is hard, but it isn't very useful. Many years ago, MacOS 9 did this, but the only useful thing was that the OS could tell you "program couldn't be launched, not enough memory". I experimented with that, and there was a range where the OS gave an error message, then a tiny range where the app crashed before it entered main, then a small range where I stopped the app without any error message because there was not enough memory for an error message, some range where I stopped the app with. an error message, and then a range where the app ran.

Comment: "it's not that it is hard":  this is as hard as the halting problem.

Comment: How could an OS do that ??

Comment: Yves, what a C program can do before it enters main() is very limited. C++ could have static class instances, but they can be executed on demand, that is not before main() is called.

Comment: The question is about "will consume along its expected life".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code

```
scanf("%d", &size); malloc(size);
```

How will the compiler calculate the amount of memory ?

---

The fact is that a default size is allocated for the heap and the stack, and these might be increased on demand at run-time, depending on the memory manager.

Comment: You can determine an upper bound given the data type of size.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess: are you kidding ?

Comment: No, but it is the only information in the code, and I do agree that it is useless, but the book may refer to that "some" OS may do something like that. Maybe simply weeding out smaller programs. Although it should take into account self modifying programs.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess: so you don't understand my post.

Comment: Do explain please

Comment: @EmmanuelMess: How will the compiler calculate the amount of memory ?

Comment: The question is about the OS calculating the memory not the compiler, and both can establish an upper bound, as neither have an oracle.